# Qt Application crashing on Raspberry Pi 3 with Adafruit 2.8" PiTfT touchscreen

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pitft, qt

I have a adafruit PiTfT 2.8" 320x240 capacitive touch display running on a raspberry pi. I cross compiled my executable under linux, where I also cross-compiled qt. If I run the enclosed example program, and touch the screen repeatedly, I get a segfault.

```
[9;0]TouchPointPressed without previous release event QQuickEventPoint(accepted:false state:Pressed scenePos:QPointF(327.487,183.617) id:2000002 timeHeld:0)
Segmentation fault
```

Here is what gdb tells me

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x72e90440 (LWP 1317)]
0x75aebf70 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56 ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0 0x75aebf70 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1 0x75aed324 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2 0x75b27954 in __libc_message (do_abort=<optimized out>,
fmt=0x75bdd6e8 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3 0x75b2db80 in malloc_printerr (action=1,
str=0x75bdd924 "double free or corruption (fasttop)", ptr=<optimized out>)
at malloc.c:4996
#4 0x75b2eb24 in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>,
have_lock=-1) at malloc.c:3840
#5 0x75e82a98 in QMapDataBase::freeTree(QMapNodeBase*, int) ()
from /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#6 0x76830204 in QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::fromNativeTouchPoints(QList<QWindowSystemInterface::TouchPoint> const&, QWindow const*, unsigned char, QEvent::Type*) () from /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#7 0x71d0aaf0 in ?? ()
```

Comment: It might be worth running gdb as root; apparently [that can cause the stack trace you got](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064637/6650102).

Comment: I tried but the crash still occurs

Comment: The first segfault you got implies that the touchscreen registered a touch  without a first touch being removed... If you tap the screen slowly do you get the segfault???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to avoid the crash: Compiling Qt with libinput support and using libinput instead of evdev.